# Lab Environment Authentication Best Practice

Tags: authentication

Looking for best practice advice regarding lab environment authentication.

We have a lab to evaluate and perform regression testing of third-party applications and hardware. No proprietary information should be used in testing.

The lab environment is segmented from the production LANs (L3) and doesn't currently have its own central authentication services (LDAP, SAML, AD, etc).

Using existing production authentication services seems risky due to the necessity of the lab environments to operate in a more dynamic and "looser" way than typical production environments. However, using local accounts can lead to its own issues related to weak credentials and lack of credential rotation.

What is your best practice for lab environment authentication?

Answer (score 1):

A test environment is still an asset for your company so you should apply the same principles and techniques that you set up on production. It is true that you can be more relaxed in terms of security because you think is a test environment, but you need to think of the damage if somebody can access it. So from my point of view, never relax the security controls that you have in place.

Comment: But sometimes you have to relax controls due to the nature of the lab, and controls need to be commensurate with the risk. The lab is an asset, sure, but do the cost of the controls outweigh the value of the asset? If you can regenerate the lab with the press of a button, why sink time and cost into robust access controls?

Comment: Depends on the lab. If the lab settings let someone bypass the corporate proxy and malware end up accessing the network, it would be a bad thing.